# Create multiple Jenkins views

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm new to groovy but I've got a piece of code that creates a view in Jenkins, which works fine as long as I'm only creating one view.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.ListView

// Retrieves the Jenkins instance
Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()

// variable definition
def viewName = 'MyView'

// view generator
jenkins.addView(new ListView(viewName))

// See created view
myView = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getView(viewName)
```

When I try to add a second view by passing a list as such `def viewName = ['MyView','MyView2']`, I get the error
`groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: hudson.model.ListView(java.util.ArrayList)`

I've added an `import java.util.ArrayList` but I still get hit with the same error.

What I expect is for the different views specified in the list to get created, but clearly, I'm missing something.

Is there a way to create a list of Jenkins views in groovy and possibly ensure that the views only get created if they don't already exist?

I noticed that in my case, the view `MyView` gets duplicated with each run.

Comment: [AddView](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/ViewGroupMixIn.html#addView-hudson.model.View-) only accepts a view object. Either make an array and iterate or add 2 views sequentially. Use getView to see if it exists. [ListView](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/ListView.html) lists existing g jobs in a View. A View can't have views in it.

Comment: Hi Ian. I'm not trying to create a View within a View. What I'm trying to accomplish is to create multiple views. My understanding of Groovy isn't great which is why I'm struggling with this. I see your point though and I'll give this a go.